# PrimeFaces p:dialog with Schedule

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have written the same codes with primefaces.org for Schedule component.I can see the schedule but not see p:dialog component when I click on a day.Here is the codes.

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

<p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule">

    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()" />
    <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()" />
    <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventMove}" update="messages" />
    <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventResize}" update="messages" />

</p:schedule>

<p:dialog appendToBody="true" widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Details" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
    <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title:" />
        <p:inputText id="title" value="#{scheduleController.event.title}" required="true"/>

        <h:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
        <p:inputMask id="from" value="#{scheduleController.event.startDate}" mask="99/99/9999">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </p:inputMask>

        <h:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
        <p:inputMask id="to" value="#{scheduleController.event.endDate}" mask="99/99/9999">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </p:inputMask>

        <h:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day:" />
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{scheduleController.event.allDay}" />

        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
        <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" actionListener="#{scheduleController.addEvent}" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();PF('eventDialog').hide();"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

And here is the *ScheduleController* class.

```
public class ScheduleController {
private ScheduleModel eventModel;

private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

public ScheduleController() {
    eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Champions League Match", previousDay8Pm(), previousDay11Pm()));
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Birthday Party", today1Pm(), today6Pm()));
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Breakfast at Tiffanys", nextDay9Am(), nextDay11Am()));
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Plant the new garden stuff", theDayAfter3Pm(), fourDaysLater3pm()));
}

public Date getRandomDate(Date base) {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTime(base);
    date.add(Calendar.DATE, ((int) (Math.random()*30)) + 1);    //set random day of month

    return date.getTime();
}

public Date getInitialDate() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.FEBRUARY, calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);

    return calendar.getTime();
}

public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
    return eventModel;
}

private Calendar today() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);

    return calendar;
}

private Date previousDay8Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date previousDay11Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date today1Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date theDayAfter3Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 2);     
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date today6Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone(); 
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date nextDay9Am() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date nextDay11Am() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date fourDaysLater3pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone(); 
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 4);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);

    return t.getTime();
}

public ScheduleEvent getEvent() {
    return event;
}

public void setEvent(ScheduleEvent event) {
    this.event = event;
}

public void addEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if(event.getId() == null)
        eventModel.addEvent(event);
    else
        eventModel.updateEvent(event);

    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
}

public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
}

public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());
}

public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event moved", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

    addMessage(message);
}

public void onEventResize(ScheduleEntryResizeEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event resized", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

    addMessage(message);
}

private void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

So why can't I see p:dialog when runnig this codes?The codes are the same with primefaces.org example.It is working fine on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I've just copied and pasted your code and did some changes to it and it worked perfectly. I'm using Primefaces version 4.

Here are the changes I've made on the View file:

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />

<h:form>
    <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onDateSelect}" update="@(.eventDetails)" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()" />
        <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventSelect}" update="@(.eventDetails)" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()" />
        <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventMove}"  />
        <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventResize}"  />
    </p:schedule>
</h:form>

<p:dialog appendToBody="true" widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Details" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
    <h:form id="dlgForm">
        <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2" styleClass="eventDetails">
            <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title:" />
            <p:inputText id="title" value="#{scheduleController.event.title}" required="true"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
            <p:inputMask id="from" value="#{scheduleController.event.startDate}" mask="99/99/9999">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </p:inputMask>

            <h:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
            <p:inputMask id="to" value="#{scheduleController.event.endDate}" mask="99/99/9999">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            </p:inputMask>

            <h:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day:" />
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{scheduleController.event.allDay}" />

            <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
            <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" actionListener="#{scheduleController.addEvent}" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();PF('eventDialog').hide();"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: It is not working. I get Cannot find component with identifier "dlgForm:eventDetails" referenced from "j_idt13:j_idt14:schedule". error.

Comment: What version of Primefaces are you using? Have you tried to reference the eventDetails in some other way?

Comment: It d'd@nt work on 4.0. I get Cannot find component with expression ":dlgForm:eventDetails" referenced from "form:j_idt12:schedule".  error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45712/discussion-between-daniel-camargo-and-emreturka)

Comment: The answer was edited using a more tolerant updating mechanism. See if that helps.